# Sony Vegas pro 15: Can not move Image in Pan/Crop

Tags: vegas-pro

I am trying to move image using pan/crop tool, but I have no idea how to do that, because there is not any "F frame". 
Thank you for advice.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Use the track motion where you can move and resize images